# Invalid data from data frame in R

Tags: r, extract, mean

I am new in R and i am trying to analyze some data. I occured an error in extracting data from data frame. This is my code:

```
library('BCA')
eggs<-read.csv2("http://jolej.linuxpl.info/Eggs.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = T, sep = ',')
weeks<-eggs$Week
eggs_prices = as.numeric(eggs$Egg.Pr)
matplot(weeks, eggs$Egg.Pr, pch = ".", type = "o", col = "blue", xlab = "Tydzień", ylab = "Cena 
jajek")
title(main = "Cena jajek w poszczególnych tygodniach")
mean(eggs_prices)
eggs_prices
```

As you can see i am trying to get eggs prices from data. Then i am creating graph and to this point everything went fine. Problem is in mean value: i am getting value: 51.61905, which is totally wrong. 
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, it was tottaly my mistake:

```
eggs<-read.csv2("http://jolej.linuxpl.info/Eggs.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = 
T, sep = ',')
```

This line cause a problem, argument stringsAsFactor should have been FALSE.